# Does series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\left(-1\right)^n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does series
$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\left(-1\right)^n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ converge?

I try to apply the alternating series test.
Thanks!

Comment: To apply the alternating test, all you really need to show is the following:

$$\sin\left(\frac1n\right)>\sin\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac1n\right)=0$$

Comment: If you tried to apply the alternating series test, I'm confused why you think it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it does.

Write $a_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \lvert \sin \frac{1}{n}\rvert$. We have

1. $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n\geq 1$ (by construction);$^{(\dagger)}$
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$;
3. $(a_n)_n$ is a decreasing sequence: indeed, $\sin$ is increasing on $[0,1]$ *(actually, even on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$)*), so $a_n = \sin\frac{1}{n}$ is decreasing.

Putting the three together,
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$ converges by the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

*$(\dagger)$ We didn't actually need the absolute values since $\sin\geq 0$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, but that way it is clearer that we do satisfy the assumptions of the theorem..*